# Excel - Connection Between Multiple IDs

Tags: excel, relationships

I have an Excel table with four columns:

1. ID #1 (sorts table)
2. ID #2
3. Attribute A for ID #2
4. Attribute B for ID #2

The Excel table shows a 1-to-1 relationship/partnership between ID #1 and ID #2 - the column for ID #1 tells me who I am referencing while the column with ID #2 tells me who ID #1 is partnered with. A single value for ID #1 could be paired with multiple values of ID #2. A value of ID #2 earlier in the list could be listed as ID #1 later on and partnered with new values. Theoretically, you could build a fairly long chain of relationships between the IDs, depending on how they are partnered.

I want to be able to run a query that tells me all the IDs that related to a specific ID, no matter how far they are separated. For example, if A is related to B, and B is related to C and D, and D is related to E, when I run a query on A, I want to see that A is related to B, C, D, and E (because they all share a connection). It doesn't have to be a query of a single instance - it could just be a complete list of the unique ID values with the related IDs.

I'm brainstorming ideas in Excel and Access to do this via a formula, but I'm drawing a blank. Any thoughts on how this might be accomplished?

Comment: You used a [sql] tag. Are you storing this data in one standalone Excel table or are you wanting to query off of a SQL table?

Comment: Sorry - I added SQL by mistake. The data is in one standalone Excel table.

Answer (score 0):

In ORACLE SQL I'd use a hierarchical query using `CONNECT BY` / `START WITH` clauses. MS Access doesn't support this.

In Excel I use a small VBA in the context of hierarchy between managers and their reports. It is recursively called and prints the hierarchy level. So if you "just" want to know who is related to whom, filter for all non-blank.

```
Sub PrintHierarchy()
Dim T As Range, Idx As Integer, Level As String, Root As String

    Root = Selection
    Set T = [DataTable]

    'start recursion
    GetReport T, Root, "1"

End Sub

Sub GetReport(T As Range, Boss As String, Level As String)
Dim Idx As Integer, Num As Integer

    Idx = 2
    Num = 1

    Do While T(Idx, 1) <> ""
        If T(Idx, 1) = Boss Then
            T(Idx, 3) = "'" & Level & "." & Num
            Num = Num + 1

            GetReport T, T(Idx, 2), T(Idx, 3)

        End If
        Idx = Idx + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Before starting this example, select columns [A:C] and name them "DataTable". Then place the cursor at the Boss column of the root node and run `Sub PrintHierarchy()`:

[image]

[image]